# sort words by length and then by alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting

Below you can see my code. It reads words from dictionary and copy words that match specific patern to test.txt. My qusetion is how to sort words in test.txt first by LENGTH and when they are sorted by length then by alphabetical order. For example.

I have:

- car
- mouse
- number
- abc
- grs

What i need

- abc
- car
- grs
- mouse
- number

My list contains over 10000 words.

```
 package test;

       import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.File;
       import java.io.FileInputStream;
      import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.FileWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
       import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class moja {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("SloveneLexicon.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                      new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
            String vrstica;
            File test = new File("test.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(test);
            while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = vrstica;
                String[] dobi_besedo_v_vrstici = s.split("\\s+");
                String prva_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[0];
                String tretja_beseda = dobi_besedo_v_vrstici[2];
                String nova_vrstica = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                Pattern ena = Pattern.compile("S\\p{L}\\p{L}ei\\p{L}*");
                    if(ena.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                    fw.write(prva_beseda+nova_vrstica);
                    fw.write("\n");}
                Pattern dva = Pattern.compile("P\\p{L}\\p{L}\\p{L}ei\\p{L}*");
                    if(dva.matcher(tretja_beseda).matches()){
                        fw.write(prva_beseda+nova_vrstica); 
                    }
                }

            fw.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? There must be thousands of questions explaining how to sort in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply add all matching words to ArrayList and then use Collections.sort with custom comparator e.g.

```
class Comparator implements Comparator<String> {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
  }
}
```

And then output sorted list to test.txt.

Or you may put matching words in TreeSet with custom comparator to be sure you don't have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should define a Comparator, so that it compares the two strings in a right manner. In your case, the shorter string will go prior to a longer string; if sizes are equal - the order is alphabetic.
Then you use this Comparator to do the sorting - use `Collections.sort()` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Collections framework List might be a good place to start, and look at Comparable/Comparators.
That might help.

Answer (score 0):

Add all your words to a list then sort using a comparator:

```
public static final Comparator<String> wordComparator = new Comparator<String>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) 
    {
        if(o1.length() == o2.length()) return o1.compareToIgnoreCase(o2);
        else return o1.length() - o2.length();
    }
};

ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
//Add words
Collections.sort(tmp, wordComparator);
```