# read words from txt file and sort them

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to read test.txt and sort it alphabeticly in order and print it to new file sort.txt. Test.txt has exactly 1 word in each line exp. :

- mouse
- car
- noun
- swat

Cant figure it out what am i missing.

MANAGE TO FIND OUT WHAT I WAS MISSING!It wrote to file but it gaves me first like 10000 empty lines then starts to output corectly.

Now to the second part.

My second question and its not related to the code is: I have to sort words by length and aplhabeticly. I was thinking first to order them alhabeticly then by length. You think that would work? Any ideas? When done all words needs to be in txt file.

```
 package test;

   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.FileReader;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.List;

    public class sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputFile = "test.txt";
    String outputFile = "sort.txt";

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
    fileReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lineList);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileWriter.close();

          }
     }
```

Comment: What is your output now

Comment: Are you saying (in your first part) you don't understand the problem you've been set?  As for the ordering, that depends on the exact wording of the question as to which should take precedent.  if it's not clear state your assumption in your code and pick an ordering.  This sounds a lot like homework so you should talk to your teacher for clarification on the problem.

Comment: This seems to be all working as expected, can't understand the question really...

Comment: i uderstand the problem but dont understand why am i getting empty file what am i missing. I am new to programming and i dont go to school. I manage to get this code together via different sites that explane how it works but now i am stuck.

Comment: You may have a file path problem... Can you find the input file ok? Are they in the same directory?

Comment: use `try-catch` for statement `FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);` etc.. to know whether file is available or not and use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) will take of closing streams. If you follow above things then you have clue of what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux u can do `cat test.txt | sort > test1.txt` from command utility. it's very simple. output will be stored in test1.txt

In java also u can use sort method for string array as below:

Read file to a string array first
///

```
        Path filePath = new File("fileName").toPath();
        Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();        
        List<String> stringList = Files.readAllLines(filePath, charset);
        String[] strNames = stringList.toArray(new String[]{});
```

Then use the below method on string array strNames, sort method to sort the array

```
            //String array
            String[] strNames = new String[]{"John", "alex", "Chris", "williams", "Mark", "Bob"};

            /*
             * To sort String array in java, use Arrays.sort method.
             * Sort method is a static method.               *
             */

            //sort String array using sort method
            Arrays.sort(strNames);

            System.out.println("String array sorted (case sensitive)");

            //print sorted elements
            for(int i=0; i < strNames.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(strNames[i]);
            }

            /*
             * Please note that, by default Arrays.sort method sorts the Strings
             * in case sensitive manner.
             *
             * To sort an array of Strings irrespective of case, use
             * Arrays.sort(String[] strArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) method instead.
             */
```

Comment: how can i do that in windows?

Comment: If u use python, it can be done very easily

Comment: i have edited my post above for java. please check

Comment: thanks manage to figure it out on my own.

Comment: i have edited it again for reading from a file.. i hope it would help

Comment: u r welcome. Please accept my solution and vote it up if ur problem is solved. Best, Mujtaba

Comment: i solved it without you solution it is posted below

Comment: I see u used what I suggested to use sort method. It is good idea to upvote as I gave my time to try to solve ur problem. U had to solve it by urself anyway but I helped. U should do it as we gave time to solve ur problem

Answer (score 0):

Implement a **Comparator** and pass it to `Collections.sort(list,comparator)`.

In your case use `Collections.sort(lineList, new MyComparator());` 
 in place of `Collections.sort(lineList);`

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    }
}
```

A comparison function, which imposes a total ordering on some collection of objects. Comparators can be passed to a sort method (such as Collections.sort or Arrays.sort) to allow precise control over the sort order. Comparators can also be used to control the order of certain data structures (such as sorted sets or sorted maps), or to provide an ordering for collections of objects that don't have a natural ordering.
Learn more from [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Maybe you could give a little more information. Like what is a comperator and how do you pass it ;)

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/sort-arraylist-using-comparator-example/

Comment: Example of exactly the comparator you'd need; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616433/sort-words-by-length-and-then-by-alphabetical-order/26616611#26616611

Answer (score 0):

Manage to make it work. It sorts words first alphabeticly and second by length. Thanks for all your replies.

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class sort {
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {  
      if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
         return 1;
      } else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
         return -1;
      }
      return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputFile = "test.txt";
    String outputFile = "sort.txt";

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
    fileReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lineList,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }   

    Collections.sort(lineList, new MyComparator());

    FileWriter Fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }       
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    fileWriter.close();

}
}
```