# sort array by length and then alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting

I'm trying to make a way to sort words first by length, then alphabetically.

```
// from
$array = ["dog", "cat", "mouse", "elephant", "apple"];

// to
$array = ["cat", "dog", "apple", "mouse", "elephant"];
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616433/sort-words-by-length-and-then-by-alphabetical-order), but it's in Java, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838227/php-sort-an-array-by-the-length-of-its-values), but it only deals with the sorting by length. I've tried sorting by length, using the code provided in the answer, and then sorting alphabetically, but then it sorts only alphabetically.

How can I sort it first by length, and then alphabetically?

Comment: can you / do you want to modify the values in the array? if yes, how about iterating over each value of the array and writing a string containing the length of the value before each value? like `"03dog", "03cat", "04mouse", "08elephant", "05apple"` and then sorting by value?

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a "how to do this" site, it is a "what is not working with my code" site. Show us what you have tried so we can offer guidance. And check out the php docs: http://php.net/docs.php

Comment: @AlienHoboken not every question has to be a debugging question, fortunately.

Comment: @Don'tPanic These kind of questions are off topic, especially when there already exist plenty of questions about how to sort arrays in PHP https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+sort+array+alphabetically

Comment: @AlienHoboken, I'm trying to do more than sort it alphabetically, if I wanted to do that I could just use a basic sort, I wouldn't need to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put both of the conditions into a `usort` comparison function.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) - strlen($b) ?: strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

The general strategy for sorting by multiple conditions is to write comparison expressions for each of the conditions that returns the appropriate return type of the comparison function (an integer, positive, negative, or zero depending on the result of the comparison), and evaluate them in order of your desired sort order, e.g. first length, then alphabetical.

If an expression evaluates to zero, then the two items are equal in terms of that comparison, and the next expression should be evaluated. If not, then the value of that expression can be returned as the value of the comparison function.

---

The other answer here appears to be implying that this comparison function does not return an integer greater than, less than, or equal to zero. It does.

Answer (score 2):

> **Note**: I didn`t post my answer early,because @Don't Panic faster then me. However,I want to add some explanation to his answer ( hope, it will be useful for more understanding).

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return strlen($a) - strlen($b) ?: strcmp($a, $b);
});
```

Ok. Function [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) waits from custom comparison function next (from docs):

> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or
>   greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be
>   respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Ok, rewrite @Don't Panic code to this view (accoding the condition above):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    //  SORT_ORDER_CONDITION_#1
    //  equals -> going to next by order sort-condition
    //  in our case "sorting alphabetically"
    if (strlen($a) == strlen($b)){
        // SORT_ORDER_CONDITION_#2
        if (strcmp($a,$b)==0) // equals - last sort-condition? Return 0 ( in our case - yes)
            return 0; //
       return (strcmp($a,$b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }else{
       return (strlen($a) < strlen ($b) ) ? - 1 : 1;
    }
});
```

**"Common sort strategy"** (abstract) with multi sort-conditions in order like `(CON_1,CON_2... CON_N)` :

```
usort($array, function(ITEM_1, ITEM_2) {
    //  SORT_ORDER_CONDITION_#1
    if (COMPARING_1_EQUALS){

        // SORT_ORDER_CONDITION_#2
        if (COMPARING_2_EQUALS){ // If last con - return 0, else - going "deeper" ( to next in order)
           //... 
             // SORT_ORDER_CONDITION_#N
             if (COMPARING_N_EQUALS) // last -> equals -> return 0;
                 return 0; 
             return ( COMPARING_N_NOT_EQUALS) ? -1 : 1;                 
           //...
        }    
        return ( COMPARING_2_NOT_EQUALS) ? -1 : 1; 
    }else{
       return ( COMPARING_1_NOT_EQUALS ) ? - 1 : 1; 
    }
});
```

In practise (from my exp), it's sorting unordered multidimensional-array by several conditions. You can use `usort` like above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as short as other methods, but I would argue that it's clearer, and can be easily extended to cover other use cases:

```php
$f = function ($s1, $s2) {
   $n = strlen($s1) <=> strlen($s2);
   if ($n != 0) {
      return $n;
   }
   return $s1 <=> $s2;
};
usort($array, $f);
```