# Sort associative array by key php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
$array = [
    0 =>
    [
        'name' => 'John',
        'age' => 24,
        'letter' => 'A'
    ],
    1 =>
    [
        'name' => 'Nathan',
        'age' => 24,
        'letter' => 'B'
    ],
    2 =>
    [
        'name' => 'Andy',
        'age' => 26,
        'letter' => 'C'
    ]
    ...
];
```

And i have only 3 **letter** types: A, B, C. So, i need sort this array by **letter** value. I need get items with **letter** value in this order: C -> A -> B.

I know i need to use **usort** method, but i don't understand how can i use it in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array that defines the order you want.

```
$order = ['C' => 0, 'A' => 1, 'B' => 2];
```

Then pass that array into the `usort` comparison function with `use`. In the comparison function, look up the sort order in the `$order` array by key using the letter from the items you're sorting.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    return $order[$a['letter']] <=> $order[$b['letter']];
});
```

---

You can also create the `$sort` array without explicitly assigning numeric values using `array_flip`

```
$order = array_flip(['C', 'A', 'B']);
```

Comment: In next case i need sort this result alphabetically by 'name'

Comment: @vasya so, sort by letter and then by name in the same sort? or resort by name?

Comment: in the same sort

Comment: @vasya check out one of my previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44835882 You can add the name to the comparison function as shown there. Let me know if you have any questions about it.