# PHP Sort array by two criteria

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$arr = [
    0 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 150
    ],
    1 => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 155
    ],
    2 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 131
    ],
    3 => [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 241
    ],
    4 => [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 45
    ],
    5 => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 23
    ],
    6 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 78
    ],
    7 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 123
    ],
    8 => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 412
    ],
    9 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 22
    ],
    10 => [
        'a' => 0,
        'b' => 11
    ],
    11 => [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 100
    ],
    12 => [
        'a' => 2,
        'b' => 105
    ],
    13 => [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 18
    ]
];
```

I want to sort the array first by the 'a' property, so all 0s, all 1s and all 2s should be together, and then all the 'b's should be ordered from lowest to highest. I hope you know what I mean. I could separate it into three arrays and then sort each one and then put them back together but I hope there's a shorter and better solution.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [`usort`](http://www.php.net/usort) should help.

Comment: @fubar I tried using something like `return a['a'] - b['a'] || a['b'] - b['b']` but didn't work

Comment: @Don'tPanic wow this worked

Comment: @nick yep. You can see my answer here for a little explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44835807/sort-array-by-length-and-then-alphabetically/44835882#44835882 Not sure where my original comment went, though (use `?:` instead of `||`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to explain why the thing you originally tried didn't work.

```
return a['a'] - b['a'] || a['b'] - b['b']
```

`||` is a [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php), so when you use that the entire expression will be evaluated as a boolean, so the only possible values are `true` or `false` (or numerically, as the `usort` comparison function should return, 0 or 1). Since none of the comparisons ended up with zeroes on both sides of the `||`, all of them evaluated to `true`, so no sorting happened.

Using `?:` instead worked because it doesn't evaluate the whole expression as a boolean, it evaluates the first part and returns the result of that, unless it's zero (equal values) in which case it goes on to evaluate the second part and return the result of that.

Example showing the difference between the two comparisons at 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/32IPa

---

You can actually sort that array more simply, though.

```
sort($arr);
```

will work. You can't always count on that working for sorting arrays, though. It just works in this case because all the inner arrays have the same keys, and you're wanting to sort by the first key, then the second. (You can see how arrays are compared in "Example #2 Transcription of standard array comparison" [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).)

Comment: What if there are more keys between the ones I want to sort? Or if they last one is before the first one? Can it still be done with sort()?

Comment: No, sort compares first the length of the two arrays, then if those are equal, compares each key/value in order. So if the columns aren't in the same order as your sort priority, you'll need to do it a different way, like usort.