# How to sort JSON with multiple conditions using PHP?

Tags: php, json, sorting

I have some JSON data that I have sorted by "sites" using usort

```
    usort($data,function($a,$b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['site'],$b['site']);
  });
```

Which results in the following

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2017-07-15 15:43:45
            [user] => ast125
            [site] => facebook
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2017-07-12 04:59:11
            [user] => ast111
            [site] => facebook
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2017-07-19 12:45:14
            [user] => ast133
            [site] => facebook
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2017-07-19 12:45:14
            [user] => ast133
            [site] => google
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2017-07-19 12:45:14
            [user] => ast125
            [site] => facebook

        )

.... and so on
```

I'm stuck because now I'm not sure how to approach sorting the users per site. 
Right now, the order is

> facebook - ast125
>
> facebook - ast111
>
> facebook - ast133
>
> google   - ast133
>
> google   - ast125

But I would like the users to be sorted while in their site group

> facebook - ast111
>
> facebook - ast125
>
> facebook - ast133
>
> google   - ast125
>
> google   - ast133

Right now, I am considering breaking the JSON array into multiple arrays (by site), and then sort the new site array by users, and then merge them back into one...

Is there an easier way for me to approach this using usort or another PHP function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44835882/2734189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easier way for me to approach this using usort or another PHP function?

Certainly.

```
usort($data, function(array $a, array $b) : int {
    return strcasecmp($a['site'], $b['site']) ?: strcasecmp($a['user'], $b['user']);
});
```

([Demo this online](https://3v4l.org/8SJ1j))

When `$a` and `$b` differ in `'site'`, the first `strcasecmp()` will return a nonzero value, so that value will be used. When they are identical, the first `strcasecmp()` will return 0, which is treated as false, so the `?:` operator will use the result of the second comparison.

This pattern can be chained to an arbitrary number of comparisons.

Comment: Hmm, another question.. how would I go about adding another condition? Once the sites are sorted, then users are sorted, I'd like the users:site sorted by time

Comment: Throw another `?: comparison()` onto the end of the statement. If you want to compare numbers, use `$b["property"] - $a["property"]`.